# UICollectionView won’t load images

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to show Flickr images in a collection view. Here's how I fetch the images in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
FlickrApi.fetchPhotos(completion: { photos, error in
    self.photos = photos as! [URL]
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
})
```

The images get fetched but they don't show up as UIImageView in `cellForItemAt` method of `UICollectionView`. Instead, I get:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

where I load the images for the cell even though the `self.photos` gets populated with image URLs before I load the images like so:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FlickrCell

    cell.flickrPhoto.pin_setImage(from: self.photos[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: @rmaddy, the `cell.flickrPhoto.pin_setImage(from: self.photos[indexPath.row])` line.

Comment: Show the `cellForAt` and the `pin_setImage` code

Comment: In that line, which property is declared as an optional? Is it `cell.flickrPhoto` or `self.photos`?

Comment: @Paolo Edited the OP with the method.     `cell.flickrPhoto.pin_setImage(from: self.photos[indexPath.row])` is where I get the error.

Comment: @rmaddy `cell.flickrPhoto` is an optional.

Comment: As discussed in the duplicate linked at the top of your question, you probably forgot to connect the cell's outlet and it is `nil` which is causing the error.